# How to pass the string from primefaces to the javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces

In primefaces ,how can I change the first letter of a word in Capital automatically on blur?
If I am using the following javaScript function , how can I pass the string from primefaces to that JS function?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
                    function changeCase(string)
{
                        alert(string);
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you're using `<h:inputText>` or `<p:inputText>`. They generate a HTML `<input type="text">` element which has a HTML DOM property `value`. You can get the HTML DOM element in the function by just passing `this` into the JS function.

E.g.

```
<h:inputText onblur="changeCase(this)" />
```

with

```
function changeCase(element) {
    var oldValue = element.value;
    var newValue = oldValue.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + oldValue.substring(1);
    element.value = newValue;
}
```

As a completely different and more robust alternative, you can also use a [`Converter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html) which runs then in the server side.